# Ethereum Mobile Application

Tags: ethereum

we are very new in Ethereum, we are going to build a mobile client application for Ethereum.
We will have following features in it like wallet, transactions, smart contracts and tokens etc.
We are thinking to keep a central server which will sync with Ethereum and every client application(mobile application) will communicate with that central server.
So that our client application will not face any delays or processing times.
Kindly confirm that this approach is ok or if you have any other better approaches, then please share with us.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First you probably want to look at Jaxx.
Second, while you totally can implement it like that,  i don't think it will be welcome by the users for 2 reasons.

The first: the coinbase wallet kinda does that already (beside the smart contracts) and it is already available.

But the main problem I see is that you want to centralize something that people appreciate to be decentralized.

Don't get me wrong, technically you can totally do it as you think. I just think your app would be much more useful if it talks to the network directly without any central(ised) server.

Comment: then please suggest us whats the right approach to implement Ethereum Wallet app. If we don't use a centralized server than each mobile app will work as node? Will mobile app sync with Ethereum itslef, if yes than mobile app will become slow and this process will be very much time consuming. Your thoughts and suggestions on that.Can you please give us some tutorial or link which can be helpful for implementation. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is very new but you can search for "ethereum light client". It is made exactly for what you want and you will find an android sample code.

Answer (score 2):

The front end part of any Ethereum dApp may communicate with the Ethereum network in the following ways:

- Local Node running on users machine:

  - Geth
  - Parity
- Online Node:

  - INFURA
- Via in-browser extension:

  - MetaMask

The simplest and becoming the standard way is to ask users to simply install MetaMask. MetaMask takes care of the users accounts (addresses and private keys) and does transactions signing in browsers, before communication with INFURA. This is all done automatically and conveniently with the least amount of friction for your end users to just use your dApp.